# need to save all the values coming in for loop?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

```
if (Username.equals(RegisteredUSer)) {
    JSONArray nameObject = msg.getJSONArray("NameList");

    for (int j = 0; j < nameObject.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject name = nameObject.getJSONObject(j);
        USername        = name.getString("FirstName");
        USerweight      = name.getString("Weight");
        Weight          = Double.parseDouble(USerweight);
    }
}
```

HERE i need to save all the username and weight coming within for loop and convert the userweight in double ,and extracting the save values within the same class??

Comment: You made a statement, but what is your question?

Comment: I know you may not be able to select answer at the moment, but if it works,please choose it after the time restriction is ended. Thank you very  much and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version:

```
ArrayList<String> username = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<Double> weight = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

if (Username.equals(RegisteredUSer)) {
    JSONArray nameObject = msg.getJSONArray("NameList");

    for (int j = 0; j < nameObject.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject name = nameObject.getJSONObject(j);
        USername        = name.getString("FirstName");
        USerweight      = name.getString("Weight");
        Weight          = Double.parseDouble(USerweight);
        username.add(USername);
        weight.add(Weight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use a string array or an arraylist.The syntax is        ArrayList  username=new ArrayList (); username.add (variablename); to extract the values call username.get (loopvariable);